# Hacer funcionar algoritmo Backtracking

Tags: java, algoritmos

Antes que nada, durante todo este tiempo atrás he estado usando este modelo para resolver mis problemas con backtracking.

Es un modelo de backtraking realizado por mi universidad https://github.com/migueltoro/apuntesjava/blob/master/SoftwareDelLibro/src/us/lsi/bt/AlgoritmoBT.java.

```
        private void bt() { 
            if(estado.isFinal()){           
                actualizaSoluciones();
                if(AlgoritmoBT.soloLaPrimeraSolucion  && solucion!=null) exito = true;
                if(!AlgoritmoBT.soloLaPrimeraSolucion  && soluciones.size()>=AlgoritmoBT.numeroDeSoluciones) exito = true;
            } else {
                    for(A a: filtraRandomize(estado,estado.getAlternativas())){  
                            if(isMin() && estado.getObjetivoEstimado(a) >= mejorValor) continue;
                            if(isMax() && estado.getObjetivoEstimado(a) <= mejorValor) continue;
                            estado.avanza(a); 
                            bt();  
                            estado.retrocede(a); 
                            if (exito) break;
                    }
            }
       }
```

Ejemplo: Como resolver el problema de las reinas con el modelo mencionado anteriormente
 https://github.com/migueltoro/apuntesjava/blob/master/SoftwareDelLibro/src/us/lsi/bt/reinas/EstadoReinasBT.java

---

Una vez leído lo anterior, comienzo con mi duda.
Estoy intentando deshacerme del modelo mencionado anteriormente para realizar mis problemas mediante backtraking, he estado intentando realizar el siguiente problema:

Tengo una lista con todos los grupos(de cantantes(Test.lista)) que puedo seleccionar, tengo 9.0€ de presupuesto para contratar los grupos con el mayor numero de votos (Maximizar votos).

Tengo bastante código realizado de lo que quiero conseguir:

**Grupos:**

```
    public class Objeto{

        private Integer codigo;
        private String nombre;
        private Integer votos;
        private Double precio;
        private Boolean cerca;

        public Objeto(Integer codigo, String nombre, Integer votos, Double precio, Boolean cerca) {
            this.codigo = codigo;
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.votos = votos;
            this.precio = precio;
            this.cerca = cerca;
        }

        public Integer getCodigo() {
            return codigo;
        }

        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        public Integer getVotos() {
            return votos;
        }

        public Double getPrecio() {
            return precio;
        }

        public Boolean getCerca() {
            return cerca;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Objeto [codigo=" + codigo + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", votos=" + votos + ", precio=" + precio
                    + ", cerca=" + cerca + "]";
        }

    }
```

**Test:**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Test {

        public static List<Objeto> lista = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
        public static Double presupuesto = 9.0;

        public static void main(String[] args){
            lista.add(new Objeto(1,"Caracola1",100,9.0,true));
            lista.add(new Objeto(2,"Caracola2",2,4.0,true));
            lista.add(new Objeto(3,"Caracola3",3,5.0,false));

            BackTraking a = new BackTraking();
            System.out.println(a.recursividad(0));
        }
    }
```

**BackTraking:**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class BackTracking {

        public List<Objeto> recursividad(Integer indice){
            List<Objeto> res = new ArrayList<Objeto>();

            if(indice == Test.lista.size()-1){
                res.add(Test.lista.get(indice));
            }else{
                for(Objeto a : getAlternativas(res)){

                    res.add(a);
                    recursividad(indice+1);
                }
            }

            return res;
        }

        public List<Objeto> getAlternativas(List<Objeto> lista) {//Todos los objetos que no sobrepasen el presupuesto y no esten en la lista
            List<Objeto> res = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
            Double coste = lista.stream().mapToDouble(x->x.getPrecio()).sum();
            for(Objeto a : Test.lista){
                if(!lista.contains(a) && (coste+a.getPrecio()) <= Test.presupuesto){
                    res.add(a);
                }
            }
            return res;
        }

    }
```

**Solución obtenida :(**

```
    [
    Objeto [codigo=2, nombre=Caracola2, votos=2, precio=4.0, cerca=true]
    , 
    Objeto [codigo=3, nombre=Caracola3, votos=3, precio=5.0, cerca=false]
    , 
    Objeto [codigo=1, nombre=Caracola1, votos=100, precio=9.0, cerca=true]
    ]
```

---

**Solución que tendría que salir :)**

El resultado obtenido tendría que ser `new Objeto(1,"Caracola1",100,9.0,true)` puesto que cumple que tiene 9.0€ de precio y el que mayor numero de votos tiene (100).

Comment: Hola.. tu publicación contiene demasiada información y es confusa. por favor expresa el problema que tienes claramente.  Por favor consulta la [ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorarla.

Comment: @gbianchi ¿Que parte del post te parece confusa?

Comment: ni se que estas preguntando y que tienen que ver todos los algoritmos mencionados

Comment: @gbianchi Es muy facil, he intentado resolver mediante backtracking un problema lo que pasa que no se como maximizarlo mediante una propiedad.

Comment: explica todo eso en el post.. el post tiene varios algoritmos, no se cual es el problema exactamente, en que de todo tu codigo esta el tema.. si tenes mas dudas, estamos en el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)

Comment: esto es mucho para mi cabecita D:

Comment: @critical-ghost Listo, he modificado el post. Contame que tal. Puedes mirar a partir de "Una vez leído lo anterior, comienzo..." que es donde hablo del problema. Saludos

Comment: @gbianchi Listo, he modificado el post. Contame que tal. Puedes mirar a partir de "Una vez leído lo anterior, comienzo..." que es donde hablo del problema. Saludos

Comment: No veo en ningun momento que compares el precio del objeto que estas procesando con el que ya tienes en la lista,simpre añades el objeto a la lista si cumple que es menor su precio que el presupuesto

Comment: @Pikoh En getAlternativa() muestro todas las alternativas posibles.(No pasen del presupuesto) Podrías darme una idea aunque sea en pseudocodigo. Te lo agradecería

Comment: Si, muestras todas las alternativas y luego, sin consultar nada, las añades a la lista `res`

Comment: @Pikoh Cierto..., ¿Tendría que eliminar el getAlternativa() o añadir una condición en mi caso base?

Comment: Hace mucho que estudié este algoritmo y no soy experto en java, pero diría que debes añadir otra condición. Siento no poder decirte mas :)

Comment: Señor usuario, le informamos que porfin vemos a alguien que si lee la guia de "como preguntar" te felicito :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analicemos tu funcion de recursividad:

```
public List<Objeto> recursividad(Integer indice){
    List<Objeto> res = new ArrayList<Objeto>(); <- Nueva lista en cada entrada
    if(indice == Test.lista.size()-1){
```

Si el indice es menor al tamaño de test.lista para todos los casos menos el ultimo

```
 res.add(Test.lista.get(indice));
```

Agrego el objeto a res, que se va a perder cuando salga por que es local

```
}else{
```

Si no es el ultimo de la lista... no se porque el ultimo lo agregas siempre.. eso es raro

```
for(Objeto a : getAlternativas(res)){
```

En teoria estas comparando los valores, sin embargo tu set de pruebas no tiene nadie que se pase...

```
res.add(a);
```

Agregas todos los objetos que son mas baratos que tu presupuesto.. y los votos donde los miras?

```
recursividad(indice+1);
                }
            }

            return res;
        }
```

Lo que veo en todo esto es lo siguiente.. No entiendo como se puede calcular lo que queres por backtracking, no hay backtracking aca, es una simple busqueda de menor valor. Supongamos que se puede por backtracking, tu algorimo deberia probar caminos (para ir y volver, no los veo aca) y comparar las dos cosas que necesitas..

Me parece que este no es el problema para aprender backtracking, y a tu algoritmo le faltan muchas cosas.

Comment: ¿te falta tabular los comentarios?

Comment: Cierto, he estado buscando problemas como el de la mochila para basarme y aprender, pero en los encontrado no realizaban llamada recursiva, por lo cual he intentado hacerlo yo. Voy a seguir investigando a ver si encuentro un problema y me sirve de ayuda. MIL GRACIAS!

Comment: @Knowledge si la respuesta te sirvio dala por aceptada para cerrar la pregunta.. estudia backtracking buscando un problema de camino minimo, que son los basicos...

Comment: @eferion estaban a proposito para que se notaran los problemas.. alguna  idea mejor?

Comment: Yo creo que si quitas los símbolos de los comentarios `//` se va a leer igual de bien y no dará la sensación de que se te ha ido la tabulación. Otra solución que yo aplico a veces es  poner numeros en cada linea a comentar y luego explicarlo en una lista numerada

Comment: @gbianchi ¿Y como ves usar el modelo ya creado https://github.com/migueltoro/apuntesjava/blob/master/SoftwareDelLibro/src/us/lsi/bt/AlgoritmoBT.java para "crear" problemas en backtracking? PD: Te lo pregunto por aquí ya que no puedo preguntarte la duda por ningún otro medio.

Comment: @Knowledge si aceptas la respuesta llegaras a la reputacion necesaria para poder ingresar al chat y hacer esta clase de preguntas.. no hay un algoritmo generico de backtracking, cada caso es diferente...

Comment: @gbianchi Es al tick verde en tu respuesta cierto?

Comment: @Knowledge sí, el tick sirve para marcar una respuesta como solución

Comment: exacto.. consulta la [ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) si tenes alguna duda.